# How can I prevent a specific application from being minimized?

Tags: kde, manjaro, music

I'm running a music visualizer called glava, but even when running in desktop mode with `/usr/bin/glava --desktop` it still allows itself to be minimized.  Obviously, for a music visualizer you got to rice your desktop, this is undesirable.  It also seems to minimize with the "show desktop" button.  I am using KDE on Manjaro.  Is there some command or flag I can use to prevent KDE from minimizing glava?  Also, I just want to mention that I am not looking for software to keep it pinned always on top, I just want to prevent it from being minimized, especially when I show desktop.

Answer (score 1):

For a managed, EWMH desktop window, the window manager is ultimately still in control and may do as it pleases. KDE has unfortunately been the most difficult for users to work with as it has some strange behavior regarding window placement, stacking order, and visibility for desktop windows (see [issue #4](https://github.com/wacossusca34/glava/issues/4)). On the bright side, KWin has extensive options for setting window rules, see: https://userbase.kde.org/KWin_Rules -- you may find a solution there.

A another workaround would be to simply ignore the window manager. GLava provides some built-in options for doing so that you can set via `#request setxwintype "!-"`. The `!` character sets unmanaged mode, and the following `-` dictates the stacking order such that it is placed below all other windows, but this isn't a perfect solution.

Source: author of GLava

Comment: That setting sounds promising for glava.  Do you know how I can set that setting?

Comment: In `~/.config/glava/rc.glsl`, there is a line with the `setxwintype` request, or via command line you can use the same option with `-r"setxwintype \"!-\""`. See [the readme](https://github.com/wacossusca34/glava/blob/master/README.md) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried, (I tested by the way);

1. Right click any border window in KDE.
2. More Options > Special Application Settings > Size & Position >
3. Check 'Minimized' set 'Force' set 'No'. Click 'OK' in bottom.
4. Test it!

---

Indeed it minimized with the 'keyboard shortcut' but not by clicking the 'minimized button' in taskbar and also by changing windows.

I believe the right solution would be in KDE as example by tricking in System Settings > Window Management > Windows Rules.

And, creating a window rule everytime it closes to reopen, but since I don't have knowledge about how to do this task, I cannot help more.

Answer (score 0):

I tried both methods described here.
They didn't help

I have another method that helps:

1. Window Rules -> Exact match "glava" -> Add property Set window type "Desktop" -> Save

Then killall glava and reopen it. Good luck!